# Problema com DataTables ID

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Estou fazendo um projeto e estou com uma dúvida/problema...
Tenho uma DataTables com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
"aoColumns": [
  {"sTitle": "<input type='checkbox' class='pull-left' id='checkall'>","mDataProp": null, "sWidth": "20px", "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' class='pull-left' id='chbItem'>", "bSortable": false},
  { "mDataProp": "itemId", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
  { "mDataProp": "codBarra", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
  { "mDataProp": "descricao", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
  { "mDataProp": "grupo.descricao", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
  { "mDataProp": "cardapio.nome", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
],
```

Como faço para recuperar o `itemId` de cada checkbox que marquei?

Eu tentei da seguinte forma (usando um método antigo):

```
var table = $('#tabela-cardapios2').dataTable();

$(document).on('click', '#btnRemover', function () {
  $('input:checked', tabelaVinculados.fnGetNodes()).each(function(index){
    console.log(tabelaVinculados.fnGetData(index).itemId);
  });
});
```

E ele até retorna o `itemId`, mas sempre dos primeiros itens, e não dos que eu marco. Por exemplo, marquei o item 3 e ele exibe o id do item 1, se marco o 3 e o 4, ele exibe o id do item 1 e 2.

Enfim, alguém sabe me dizer como recupero esse ID usando a versão atual do DataTables? Se ninguém souber, pode ser usando a versão antiga mesmo, como tentei fazer ali...

-EDIT-

No meu JSP não tem nada na criação da tabela, somente o corpo dela:

Cód. interno
            Cód. barras
            Descrição
            Grupo
            Cardápio
        
    
    
    
    
        
            
            Código interno
            Código de barras
            Descrição
            Grupo
            Cardápio

Aqui está onde eu crio a tabela de fato

```
function visualizaProdutos(cardapio) {
    var table = $('#tabela-vinculados').DataTable( {
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 100, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 100, "Todos"]],
    "pageLength": 10,
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "cursor": "pointer",
    destroy: true,
    "sAjaxSource": "visualizaProdutos/" + cardapio,
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "widget", "value": "token" } );
            request = $.ajax({
              "dataType": 'json', 
              "type": "GET", 
              "url": sSource, 
              "data": aoData, 
              "success": fnCallback
            });
      },
      "aoColumns": [


            { "mDataProp": null, "sWidth": "20px", "sDefaultContent": "<label class='switch'><input value='itemId' id='chbRemover' type='checkbox'><div class='slider round'></div></label>", "bSortable": false},
            { "mDataProp": "itemId", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
            { "mDataProp": "codBarra", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
            { "mDataProp": "descricao", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
            { "mDataProp": "grupo.descricao", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
            { "mDataProp": "cardapio.nome", "sDefaultContent" : ""},
        ],
    });

table.ajax.reload(null, false);
}
```

O que está acontecendo, é que eu até consigo pegar meu `itemId`, só que está vindo de produtos aleatórios, segue exemplo:

[image: Console]
**Selecionei o produto 105023 e me retornou o 837032**

Obrigado desde já.

--Solução--

Mudei o tipo de selecionar os itens da tabela, usando:

```
        "select": {
         style: 'multi'
    },
```

No click do botão, fiz o seguinte para pegar os ID's:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < tabela2.rows('.selected').data().length; i++) { 
        console.log( tabela2.rows('.selected').data()[i].itemId);
    }
```

Comment: Oi Giovani, não sei quanto a DataTables, mas tenho uma ideia: você pode pegar todos os input da página usando document.getElementsByTagName("input"), e passar por cada um deles verificando se é do tipo checkbox e caso seja, verificar se checked é igual a checked, caso seja, você pega o id desse elemento e guarda.

Comment: Ótima ideia, vou tentar fazer isso... Muito obrigado pelo retorno!

Comment: Tentei fazer dessa forma e não funcionou, esse método que usava antes, se for parar pra pensar, já fazia isso. O maior problema é que eu não consigo ler o ID do item que está naquela linha em que o checkbox foi marcado...

Comment: Tem como vc colar uma parte do html da tabela gerada pra ajudar a gente a criar uma solução?

Comment: Eu tinha escrito para vc verificar se checked era igual a checked, mas na verdade tem q verificar se checked é igual a true ou false.

Comment: Antonio, mudei a pergunta, fornecendo maiores informações... Obrigado pelo retorno até então pessoal!

Comment: Seria bom ver o código gerado mesmo, pq pode ser que o html que está sendo montado pelo javascript já esteja vindo com problema. visualizando tudo é mais fácil de detectar porque o problema ocorre. No Firefox existe uma extensão chamada Webdeveloper Toobar. Após instalar essa extensão no Firefox aparece uma barrinha de utilidades, o botão "Ver código fonte" no final dessa barrinha tem uma opção chamada "Ver código fonte gerado" que mostra como está o html(dom da página) naquele instante, com todos os pedaços de html que o javascript criou na memória.

Comment: Firefox: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/  Extensão Webdeveloper Toolbar: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda! Consegui resolver de outra forma, tirei os checkbox e usei a opção de seleção do DataTables mesmo. Para quem interessar, irei editar a pergunta com a solução...

Comment: Poderia postar a solução no campo da resposta? Assim fica mais organizado.

Comment: tu ta usando sintaxe antiga do datatables

Answer (score 0):

Solução encontrada:

Mudei o tipo de selecionar os itens da tabela, usando:

```
    "select": {
     style: 'multi'
},
```

No click do botão, fiz o seguinte para pegar os ID's:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabela2.rows('.selected').data().length; i++) { 
    console.log( tabela2.rows('.selected').data()[i].itemId);
}
```